# Access current row (not previous row) in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression (CTE)

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

## [DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0cdffc484d5efd0895838c4e99861558)

## SAMPLE CODE

```
create table lifetable (
    age int,
    qx decimal(8, 6)
);

insert into
    lifetable
values (18, 0.000066),
    (19, 0.000130),
    (20, 0.000244),
    (21, 0.000256),
    (22, 0.000289),
    (23, 0.000301),
    (24, 0.000377),
    (25, 0.000406),
    (26, 0.000431),
    (27, 0.000442),
    (28, 0.000456),
    (29, 0.000476),
    (30, 0.000566);


create table people (
    age int,
    name varchar(10)
);

insert into
    people
values (18, 'George'),
    (23, 'William'),
    (27, 'Kate');

;with cte as (
    select
        name,
        p.age,
        qx,
        cast(iif(p.age > 30, 0, 1) as decimal(10, 7)) as pxaa,
        cast(iif(p.age > 30, 0, 1) as decimal(10, 7)) as tpxaa
    from people as p
    left join lifetable as lt
        on p.age = lt.age

    union all

    select
        name,
        cte.age + 1,
        lt.qx,
        cast(pxaa * lt.qx as decimal(10, 7)), -- as pxaa
        /****
        ** I need the current value of pxaa and the previous value of tpxaa to calculate
        ** the sebsequent values of tpxaa
        **/
        cast(lead(pxaa) over (partition by name order by cte.age asc) * tpxaa as decimal(10, 7)) -- as tpxaa
    from cte
    join lifetable as lt
        on cte.age + 1 = lt.age

    where cte.age < 30
) select * from cte order by name, age option (maxrecursion 0);
```

In this particular case, the column tpxaa starts with 1 or 0 in the first row and from the second row on the values for tpxaa are calculated using its previous value (previous row in the tpxaa column) and the current value (current row in the pxaa column) of pxaa which is another column whose values are also calculated.

I don't know what to do but to use a recursive CTE. But the recursive CTE only access the previous row. Which is good since I can get the previous row of tpxaa, but I also get the previous row of pxaa what's an undesired behaviour.

I tried using OUTER APPLY in the pxaa column, but SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) gives me the message

> *The recurive member of the CTE has multiple recursive references*

LAG and LEAD will bring NULL values. Maybe because the values of pxaa are also being calculated

CROSS APPLY will give me a cartesian product that I don't want.

In Excel, the references can be visualized:

[image]

How do I calculate a column whose values depend on its own previous row and the current row of another calculated column in SQL Server?

Comment: Add a previoustpxaa column to the CTE.

Comment: Hi, @avery_larry, how will this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**disclaimer**

I'm not actually very good at recursive CTEs.  I don't think this code is completely correct for you, but I think it might give you an idea of what I think you'll need to do:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        name,
        p.age,
        qx,
        cast(iif(p.age > 30, 0, 1) as decimal(10, 7)) as pxaa,
        cast(iif(p.age > 30, 0, 1) as decimal(10, 7)) as tpxaa,
        cast (1 as decimal(10, 7)) as previoustpxaa -- I'm not sure what you want for the initial "previous" value of tpxaa since there is no such thing
    from people as p
    left join lifetable as lt
        on p.age = lt.age

    union all

    select
        name,
        cte.age + 1,
        lt.qx,
        cast(pxaa * lt.qx as decimal(10, 7)) as pxaa,
        cast(pxaa * previoustpxaa as decimal(10, 7)) as tpxaa, -- not sure if this should be pxaa * lt.qx * previoustpxaa or something else
        tpxaa as previoustpxaa -- here is where you record the current as the previous
    from cte
    join lifetable as lt
        on cte.age + 1 = lt.age

    where cte.age < 30
) select * from cte order by name, age option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: I'll try your solution, @avery_larry. Get back soon. Thank you

Comment: That was a nice try, but tpxaa starts with one or zero, so in the first iteration the value of tpxaaprevious assumes 1 or zero, since it gets its values from tpxaa.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're having.  The "first" value of previoustpxaa is never used.

Comment: I'm guessing tpxaa should be `cast(pxaa * lt.qx * previoustpxaa as decimal(10,7)) as tpxaa`

Comment: What should the `pxaa` calculation be?  I think `pxaa * lt.qx` might be wrong.

Comment: If you change it to subtraction instead of multiplication, it looks a lot like your chart.  `cast(pxaa - lt.qx as decimal(10, 7)) as pxaa,` and `cast((pxaa - lt.qx) * previoustpxaa as decimal(10, 7)) as tpxaa,`

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c144087f3fd1e14993bafa01576c29f